# How to send xml string from action class to jsp in struts2

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am very much new to struts 2. I am creating a sample example. In my example i have a **login.jsp**. Currently i have not implemented any logic in my jsp page, i am just checking if the user has inputed value in username and password textBox. From the login.jsp, the control gets redirected to **callWebservice.java** action class. Here i am calling a webservice which is giving me result in form of xml. On **success** i am redirecting from this action class to **showResult.jsp**. **Here i want to capture my result xml in a variable using javascript**. 
Here is my code on showResult.jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Result</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showResult() {
            alert("Here it comes ");
var result =  <s:property value="key1" />
            alert("Before Display");
        }
    </script>
</head>


<body onload="showResult()">
<form action="#" method="POST" >
<div id="headerbg">
<h1 id="headerTag">Webs service Result</h1>
</div>
Result obtained by invoking webservice is  : <s:property value="key1" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the result xml from this property tag i.e `<s:property value="key1" />`.

> I just want to know how can i store this result in a variable using
>   JAVASCRIPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `var result` as

```
var result = "<s:property value='key1'/>";
```

**i.e.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showResult() {
    alert("Here it comes ");
    var result = "<s:property value='key1'/>";
    alert("Before Display");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
var result =  <s:property value="key1" />
```

by

```
var result =  "<s:property value=\"key1\" />"
```

Comment: You can't (nor need to) escape struts tags that way